# how to open a new browser insatnce not tab with angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to open a new window when clicking on a button ,i used this way

```
 $scope.openInNewWindow = function () {
            $window.open('/newwindow.html', '_blank');
        }
```

but it always opens a new tab, but i need a new browser instance

Comment: No, you can't open a browser instance with new tab.. First place why you need that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target='\_blank' to show in new window, NOT new tab, possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834559/target-blank-to-show-in-new-window-not-new-tab-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  http://plnkr.co/edit/f50fWHnLBC3Y43mx6iuO?p=preview

```
$window.open('/newwindow.html',"_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
```