# How to open new window in other screen with specific location in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, screen, accessibility

The problem is that I want to use Javascript to manage a group of 20+ windows and most of them locate in different screens (up to 9). I would like to save/restore position of all those windows so that the user do not have to re-locate all of them windows every time they use the app.

I tried APIs such as `window.moveBy`, `window.open` and `window.moveTo` by supplying `clientX` larger than screen width but still not work. The windows are "clipped" in the bound of the current screen. My machine is running Google Chrome v59.0 and CentOS 7.

Is there any method, public API or even private API (as a last resort) to do so? I have checked the W3C standard and found nothing about that. Although some online resources claim that they can control window in new screen but they do not work on Chrome.

Comment: Could this help you ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up

Comment: Thanks I tried this in chrome but it does not work.

Comment: How is this related to *accessibility* and what W3C standard are you talking about?

Comment: I checked that but they provide nothing related to multiple screens. Only the CSS Objects Model extends some screen API. (Ref: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify on the href target the attribute "_blank".
Keep in mind that this attribute means that the new location will be opened in another tab not window!

You can't control this aspect, reasons? Here: [Target='_blank' to show in new window, NOT new tab, possible or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834559/target-blank-to-show-in-new-window-not-new-tab-possible)

Comment: Thanks but I need more than opening a new tab. And it is already possible to open a new window (not tab) using standard JavaScript. All I need is to control the screen which the new window locates in. This may require non-standard/browser specific JavaScript.