# Using NavigateUrl, how to open a new window instead of a tab in the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a page that presents a bunch of part numbers to my users.  I want a new window to open when the user clicks on a part number.  The [MSDN page for NavigateURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to indicate that I just put `Target="_blank"` in the properties for the Hyperlink, but that just pops a new tab (in Chrome if it matters).

How do I get it to pop a new window instead of a new tab?  I tried to delete the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` property because it seemed extraneous, but it didn't like that and told me that `"Target was not a valid option for a hyperlink"`, or something to that effect (if it's important I can get the exact error).

Here's my code:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Part Number"
DataTextField="partNumber"
DataNavigateUrlFields="partNumber"
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PartLookup.aspx?partNumber={0}"
NavigateUrl="PartLookup.aspx?partNumber={0}"
Target="_blank"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser being used decides how to handle being given a `target="_blank"`, and you can not control whether it chooses to make a new tab or window.

You can use Javascript to force the opening of a new window, but I do not believe that can be done through your HyperLinkField directly.

[See this issue for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834559/target-blank-to-show-in-new-window-not-new-tab-possible)

Comment: Thanks for that, I've been able to get it to open a new Window in IE (which is what the primary user of this feature will be using), so I can show her how to do that.